# restore native setter/getter

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

I have explored how the getter/setter works...

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 'This will change the site';

Object.defineProperty(document.body, 'innerHTML', {
    get: function(){
        console.log('[FAKED] document.innerHTML');
        return false;
    },
    set: function(val){
        console.log('[FAKED] document.innerHTML = '+val);
        return false;
    }
});

alert(document.body.innerHTML); // false
```

This could be a good thing to do if the browser did not support innerHTML or you want do make a good pollyfill for the `<progress>`. However if you are stupid enough to execute this code. how could you revert it back to the way it was before?

Comment: What do you mean revert? This is executed in your webpage so, you'll juste have to reload the page without that part of the script no?

Comment: What browsers do not support innerHTML? :)

Comment: The thing to consider is probably a best practice; like do not overwrite native functionality of the browser unless your intention is to breed incompatibility.

Comment: you can easily revert the code by pressing `Ctrl+A` and then `Delete` ;)

Comment: just took innerHTML as an example...

Comment: If your intent is to create a `polyfill`, there shouldn't ever be a need to `restore` as they should only ever fill in gaps -- `if (!('innerHTML' in document.body)) Object.defineProperty(...);`

Answer (score 2):

You destroyed the browser definition of `.innerHTML`.

There is no going back...

Comment: To bad :( was hopping you could "clone" the native code someway so you could restore it...

Comment: you could get the native code from somewhere else and redefine innerHTML  don't ask me where though

Comment: I have no idea.  I suggest reinstalling your browser if it's that big of a deal for you  Wait, were you asking me or him?

Comment: asked PitaJ... Was thinking about making a polyfill for unsuported video codec... so you could get the video.curentTime from a flash/quicktime player and the revert it back to html5 with all event and such thing